# «Скажіть», «як ви думаєте» тощо в питальних реченнях

Tags: правопис, пунктуація

1. «Скажіть, будь ласка, як звідси дістатися до вокзалу?»
2. «Скажіть, будь ласка: як звідси дістатися до вокзалу?»
3. «Скажіть, будь ласка, як звідси дістатися до вокзалу.»

Який з цих варіантів правильний? Тут є два моменти:

1. Чи потрібен знаки питання в кінці? Чи питальне це речення?
2. Який розділовий знак потрібний після «будь ласка»?

Ще приклади:

1. «Підкажіть, де тут поблизу можна поміняти валюту?»
2. «Підкажіть: де тут поблизу можна поміняти валюту?»
3. «Підкажіть, де тут поблизу можна поміняти валюту.»

Який з трьох варіантів?

Або таке:

1. «Як думаєте, зроблять вони це вчасно?»
2. «Як думаєте: зроблять вони це вчасно?»

Тут зі знаком питання зрозуміло, але є сумнів щодо розділових знаків після «думаєте».

Буду вдячний, якщо хтось підкаже, на що посилатися, чим керуватися. Можливо, де знайти відповідні правила в чинному правописі.

Дякую заздалегідь.

Comment: В усіх реченнях слід ставити знак питання. Після «будь ласка», «підкажіть» та «як думаєте» на загальних підставах можна поставити або кому (трохи більш звично), або двокрапку (трохи менш звично; можливо, із загостренням уваги на тексті, який ітиме далі).

Comment: Вставні слова та словосполучення https://zno.if.ua/?p=4322

Answer (score 1):

Після «будь ласка» потрібна кома, адже це вставна конструкція. Якщо вилучити її, то вийде: «Скажіть, як звідси дістатися до вокзалу?»
Двокрапка в складнопідрядному реченні ставиться, якщо друга частина: а) виражає причину того, про що говориться в першій (до неї можна поставити питання *чому?*, а перед нею вжити сполучник *бо*); б) доповнює або розкриває зміст першої частини (до неї можна поставити питання *а що?*). Таким чином, двокрапка після «будь ласка», «підкажіть», «як думаєте» не має сенсу.